# How can I fix Lion Mail's search functionality?

Tags: macos, mail.app, search

I made a clean install of Lion, configured Mobile Me in System Preferences.

So, when I opened Mail, my Mobile Me account was already configured and it started downloading my mails.

Everything worked fine except search. I can't search among every mails. The only search I can do using is "from" or "to" a contact of my address book.

Searching the web, I discovered some potential solutions that I tried unsuccessfully. Here's a list of what I already done :

- repairing permissions
- disabling Spotlight and re-enabling Spotlight for my whole disk (via the preference pane & via the terminal)
- deleting the "envelope-index" file and get mail re-index all my mails
- rebuilding each mailboxes
- deleting `~/Library/Mail`, `~/Library/Mail Downloads`, `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.*` in order to start over
- starting again from my `~/Library/Mail` folder from my Snow Leopard installation.
- starting again without configuring Mobile Me in system preferences but directly in Mail (as different computer user)

None of these actions fixed my problem.

Have you got any ideas?

#### Edit :

I made a new clean install of Lion on an external hard drive, configured my Mobile Me account directly when opening Mail.app and everything worked fine. I tried to copy Mail.app-related files to my main installation of Lion, but that didn't work. My latest solution would be install Lion again on my internal hard drive, but I would prefer not to do so. I'm still hoping there's another solution.

Comment: What happens when you try a search? Are there erros? Do no results show up?

Comment: No error, no result. However, I think a "token" should be created and it is not. When I search for a contact, it creates a token. When I search among all content, it doesn't create any token. As I didn't try Lion on any other computer, I am not sure how things should be. If a screenshot would be helpful, please let me know what you would like to see. Thank you !

Comment: I would restore a copy of your Snow Leopard mail folders from ~/Library/Application Support to a new user on your Lion to see if it just needs a fresh attempt at rebuilding the database for Lion. You can do this while the network is off to avoid contamination / confusion. (and if spotlight sees into none of the mail files - then you have deeper spotlight privacy or corruption issues)

Comment: I have no solution for you, but wanted to chime in that I have the same problem and would be very happy indeed if someone did have a solution. (What is even weirder is that I can search for keywords in Spotlight, but not Mail.)

Comment: A Spotlight search was also working for me. I solved my problem by reinstalling Lion, but you should look at my question to see every things I tried, maybe one of them will work for you.

Comment: I’ve got the same problem. This is a rather huge bug. I’m still hoping for Apple to develop a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a clean install of Lion again and configuring Mail.app before the Mobile Me preferences pane solved the problem for me.

(this didn't work as a new user on my old installation)

That's probably overkill, but I tried everything I could without success, so…

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it turned out the index was broken.

A rebuild didn't work for me so I had to quit Mail and type (in the terminal):

```
cd ~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/
rm -rf Envelope\ Index Envelope\ Index-shm  Envelope\ Index-wal
```

After that, reopening the Mail app took some time for the index to rebuild but it fixed the search index.

Thanks to [MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1212277) for the answer

Comment: I already did that, see my question. Also, I reinstalled Lion and it worked well, see my answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if we are having the same problem but I initially thought we did until I fixed it. For some reason I had the "Mail" folder under the Privacy tab in Spotlight in System Preferences.

Removing the folder from the and Mail worked fine again.

I doubt you did the same but I can't hurt mentioning this..

Answer (score 1):

Does restoring a copy of your Snow Leopard mail folders from ~/Library/Application Support to a new user in Lion have the same problem? That's saved me in the past when an upgrade didn't work so well in mail.

Comment: I'm sorry to answer you so late but I didn't got the chance to try before now. I just tried and it didn't work, unfortunately. Thanks anyway !

Comment: Wow - that's unfortunate - the remaining potential culprits are going to be hard to test / fix. OS level issues or some data specific bug are the worst to troubleshoot.

Comment: Unfortunate it is ! I tried a new clean install and it worked (see "edit" section in my question). Something goes wrong on my main install, but what ?

Comment: Ugh. Would you try moving the folder ~/Library/Mail/V2 to the desktop or the trash while Mail is quit? You might be able to get it to re-download the content rather than reinstalling Lion.

Comment: Still no luck… :( I'll probably reinstall this weekend. Thank you for your advices !

Answer (score 0):

Go to Mail preferences > Accounts > MobileMe account > Advanced tab. Look for a setting labeled "Keep copies of messages for offline viewing", and make sure it is set to keep copies of messages, otherwise Spotlight can't populate its index with your message contents.

Comment: I already checked that and it keeps local copies of messages. Unfortunately, this won't be the solution to my problem. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my IMAP accounts and I could only search for keywords in new emails (= mails that arrived AFTER I upgraded to Lion). Rebuilding the index solved this problem for me.

Mailbox -> Rebuild

See also: http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mail/2.0/en/ml1136.html

Comment: As I said in the question, I already tried to rebuild my mailboxes (more than once). In addition, the search in content never worked in my case (old or new mails). Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to delete the index files which Mail rebuilt unprompted:

https://plus.google.com/105247387818704991250/posts/LzvM2sfa1rX

Comment: I already did that, see my question. Also, I reinstalled Lion and it worked well, see my answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Comment: The link is now broken, so this answer has become more or less worthless (especially since someone else has given intstructions on deleting index files in another answer)

Answer (score 0):

You should also try deleting the Spotlight index and forcing Spotlight to re-index your entire hard drive.

I'm sure there's a command line action for this, but I use the commercial utility MacPilot.

[image]

Comment: I already did that, see my question. Also, I reinstalled Lion and it worked well, see my answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My Mail and spotlight searching stopped working at some point in 10.7.2.

Re-Indexing Spotlight did not work nor rebuilding the Mail inboxes.

What just now seems to have worked though, is I notice there was a "_spotlight" user listed on my Users folders permissions.  This I think is something to do with ACL. Doing a search, I found that you could try and get spotlight to index [on attached AFP partition](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3006000?start=0&tstart=0) And the "_spotlight" user was involved.

Using apples server app I shared my **Users** folder. This re added the "_spotlight" with custom permissions. And I deleted the old one ("_spotlight" ) from the same user permissions pane.

I un-checked all share options. i.e afp smb.

Spotlight started indexing and I can now do searches in Mail and the finder.

If I Un-share again I cannot get search results. Switch sharing on again I can.

Comment: Thanks markhunte, I didn't correlate my Mac OS X Lion Mail search breaking with my installing the Lion Server tools. I saw that the Lion server started the File Sharing server for me, which I wasn't using. I removed all the share points and disabled the File Sharing server. Later I noticed that Mail search was broken, but your post is what put it together for me. Re-adding the /Users share point and re-enabling File Sharing in Server.app allowed Mail.app search to work again.